# Convergence of the Mellin transform of $\zeta(s)\, \Gamma(s)$ for line integrals with real part $\le 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, integral-transforms, euler-product

This question is inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1922814/the-mellin-transform-for-etas-gammas-and-information-about-the-distribu), however I believe is quite different.

The Mellin transform for:

$$\displaystyle \Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)= \int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \frac{1}{e^x-1}\,dx$$

equals:

$$\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int_{c-\infty\,i}^{c-\infty\,i} s^{-x}\,\zeta(x)\,\Gamma(x)  \,dx =\frac{1}{e^s-1}$$

and is only valid for $c>1$ (the relation breaks down for $c\le 1$, although the LHS still converges).

However, when I replace $\zeta(s)$ by its series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$ or its associated Euler-product $\prod_{primes} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ then numerical evidence suggests that the relation remains valid for $0 < c \le 1$.

I tested for increasing $v$:

$$\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int_{c-v\,i}^{c-v\,i} s^{-x}\,\prod_{n=1}^v \frac{1}{1-p_n^{-s}} \,\Gamma(x) \,dx =\frac{1}{e^s-1}$$

and found using Pari/GP (with high real precision) embedded in SageMath for e.g. $s=\frac12, c=\frac12$:

> gp("default(realprecision,1200)")
>
> gp("tes(s,c,v)=1/(2*Pi*I) * intnum(x = c-v * I, c+v * I, 1/(s^x)*prodeuler(p=1,v,(1/(1-p^(-x))))*gamma(x))")
>
> gp("tes(1/2,1/2,33)")
>
> 1.54149844959303269369...

and this gets increasingly closer to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}-1}$. It actually seems to work for all $c,\Re(s) > 0$.

I was a bit surprised by these numerical results (they might be wrong!), since the Euler product in the integrand clearly diverges for $c\le 1$.

Is this result correct and if so, is this actually what one would expect happening after applying a Mellin transform on an analytically continued function?

Maybe the integral annihilates certain infinities when running through the line $c \pm \infty i$ or maybe is it the $s^{-x}$ that "regulates" the Euler product?

Thanks.

Comment: $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} \right)dx$ converges for $Re(s) \in (0,1)$, and  $\Gamma(s)\prod_{p< x} (1-p^{-s})^{-1} = \Gamma(s) \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} 1_{\max_{p |n} p < x}$ is the Mellin transform of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nx} 1_{\max_{p |n} p < x}$ (converging for $Re(s) > 0$)

Comment: Thanks (again) user1952009. I now see that: $$\frac{1}{2\,\pi\,i}\int_{c-\infty\,i}^{c-\infty\,i} s^{-x}\,\zeta(x)\,\Gamma(x)  \,dx =\frac{1}{e^s-1}-\frac{1}{s}$$ for $\Re(s) \in (0,1)$ (found the deriviation on p22/23 in Titchmarsh book on the Zeta function). However, hadn't appreciated that the finite series/Euler products would still converge as well.